# How to write test cases for pickle backwards compatibility

Tags: python, pickle

You're writing a library, and you know your users pickle your object.  Sometimes you add new fields, and this creates a BC problem because old pickles of the objects don't have the needed fields. You'd like to add some tests for this case.

The obvious way to do this is to save some actual pickles from your old version, shove them in your test suite somehow, and make sure you can keep unpickling them.  But having hard-coded binary test data is pretty uncool. Is there a way to write tests without having to do some manual binary? I've tried playing around with "faking" the `__module__` and `__qualname__` fields on a locally declared class (which is intended to simulate the "old" version) but I get errors like "_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : it's not the same object as torch.nn.modules.conv.Conv2d" Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to add defaults to fields that are both newly added and required? Are you asking about testing the loading of the old pickled data? I would just have the raw pickled data for testing, because if you use code to generate that, then you have the problem of wondering if that code is correct and if it needs to be tested.

Comment: I was afraid of hearing that :)

Comment: Yeah, I understand your reticence, but if you put that pickled testing data in a separate file it could be re-used by multiple tests.